# Double symmetrization in Einstein index notation

Tags: field-theory, tensor-calculus, definition, notation

What does the following supposed to give? This appears in equation (3.12) in the following link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5344 (last term)

$$A^{(I(J}B^{K)L)} = $$

$$1) \quad \frac{1}{2}(A^{(IJ}B^{KL)}+A^{(IK}B^{JL)})=\frac{1}{4}(A^{IJ}B^{KL}+A^{KL}B^{IJ}+A^{IK}B^{JL}+A^{JL}B^{IK})$$
$$2) \quad \frac{1}{2}(A^{(IJ}B^{KL)}+A^{(IK}B^{JL)})=\frac{1}{4}(A^{IJ}B^{KL}+A^{LJ}B^{KI}+A^{IK}B^{JL}+A^{LK}B^{JI})$$

$$\text{3)} \quad \text{Something else?}$$

Here, I assume that the author is using $A^{(I}B^{J)}=\frac{1}{2}(A^I B^J+A^J B^I).$

Comment: Anyone can invent a notation. Without context this does not mean much.

Comment: This appears in (as I have now edited the question) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5344.pdf, equation (3.12) last term. Indeed, I could not find the definition of the notation inside this paper.

Comment: Why not contact the author?

Comment: I have never contacted any authors in my life, but would this be an appropriate situation to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Beem et al are free to contradict my inference, but the most natural generalization of$$2A^{(I}B^{J)}=A^IB^J+I\leftrightarrow J$$to your example is to perform $+X\leftrightarrow Y$ operations in the order indicated by nested brackets, viz.$$\begin{align}4A^{(I(J}B^{K)L)}&=(A^{IJ}B^{KL}+J\leftrightarrow K)+I\leftrightarrow L\\&=A^{IJ}B^{KL}+A^{IK}B^{JL}+A^{LJ}B^{KI}+A^{LK}B^{JI},\end{align}$$i.e. option 2.